# Jquery sortable-ui inside a dialog-ui that loads a page via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, cakephp, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a user management system written in CakePHp v1.3 where I want to sort the users. 
So I am using jquery dialog-ui (let's say similar to facebook friends list) and loading this via a ajax page with latest users added.

In this list I want to be able to use jquery sortable-ui but for some reason I cannot. 
I guess the javascript is not loaded? 
I cannot see in firebug if this is happening or not so if anyone knows what can be done please help me.

Heres the code:
This triggers the dialog:

```
<div onClick="manageCoauthors(data={'id':'<?php echo $this->params['pass'][0]; ?>'});" class="floatRight allImg leftManageFDs" style="cursor: pointer"></div>
```

Then this is the javascript for opening the dialog:

```
$('#dialog-manage-coauthors').load(fdBaseUrl + 'publications/ajaxManageCoauthors/' + paperID).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        width:500,
        height:400,
        buttons:{
            "OK": function(){
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
```

And the content of the page loaded with ajax that will populate the dialog-ui container

```
<style>
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; cursor: move }
#sortable li { margin: 3px 3px 3px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 50px; height: 50px; font-size: 4em; text-align: center; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //initialize sortable
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        /*update: function(){
            var order = $('#sortable').sortable('serialize');
            $.ajax({
                url: fdBaseUrl + 'cv/orderParahraphs',
                data: order,
                dataType: 'json'
            })
        }*/
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});



</script>
<?php
    if(isset($publicationColaborators) && !empty($publicationColaborators)){
        ?>
        <ul id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">
        <?php
        foreach($publicationColaborators as $colaboratorDetail){

            //debug($colaboratorDetail);
            $profile_image = 'users/profile/' . 
                                md5((isset($colaboratorDetail['User']) ? $colaboratorDetail['User']['id'] : $colaboratorDetail['id'])) . DS . 
                                (isset($colaboratorDetail['User']) ? $colaboratorDetail['User']['profile_photo'] : $colaboratorDetail['profile_photo']);
            $options = array('gender'=>(isset($colaboratorDetail['User']) ? $colaboratorDetail['User']['gender'] : $colaboratorDetail['gender']), 
                                'size' => '40',
                                'link'=>(isset($colaboratorDetail['User']) ? $colaboratorDetail['User']['slug'] : $colaboratorDetail['slug']),
                                'title'=>$this->Fellow->fullUserVisitCard((isset($colaboratorDetail['User']) ? $colaboratorDetail['User'] : $colaboratorDetail)));
            ?>
            <li class="ui-state-default">
                <div class="floatLeft" style="padding:10px;">

                        <div onClick="removeColaborator(data={'id':'<?php echo (isset($colaboratorDetail['User']) ? $colaboratorDetail['User']['id'] : $colaboratorDetail['id']); ?>', 'paperID':'<?php echo $paperID; ?>'})" style="position: absolute; margin-left:27px" class="allImg wall_post_actions_delete_active"></div>
                        <?php
                        echo $this->Fellow->checkImage($profile_image, $options); 
                        ?>

                </div>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        </ul>
        <?php
    }
    else{
        echo __d('publications', 'You have no co-authors yet', true); 
    }
?>
<div class="clearDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is that the `document.ready` call won't re-trigger on the AJAX'd content, so your sortable never gets called.

What you need to do is add the sortable in the next parameter of the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function which is a callback that triggers when the `load()` itself has finished.

```
$('#dialog-manage-coauthors').load(fdBaseUrl + 'publications/ajaxManageCoauthors/' + paperID, function() {
    //initialize sortable
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        /*update: function(){
            var order = $('#sortable').sortable('serialize');
            $.ajax({
                url: fdBaseUrl + 'cv/orderParahraphs',
                data: order,
                dataType: 'json'
            })
        }*/
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
}).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        width:500,
        height:400,
        buttons:{
            "OK": function(){
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
```

This will obviously go in the parent page.

Comment: No, I was trying this also before but the sortable is not present to do his thing. Maybe you can give me a hint how to debug this and check what comes with the ajax page?